# Nullpointer Exception with image gallery

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-gallery

i get string theme_name in database sqlite and then use theme name to set a image in gallery . But i have some error with nullpointer exception. Can you tell me why happen ? and how can i do ? Thank you

this is my code

```
 public class MybookActivity_Gallery extends Activity{

private BooksDB db;
private Context context;
private HashMap< String, ArrayList<String>> hm;
private ImageView imgOldSelected;
private int resID;
private ImageView img_shelf;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_mybookactivity_gallery);
    context = this;
    db = new BooksDB(context);
    ArrayList<String> list_bokID = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list_title = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list_theme = new ArrayList<String>();
    hm = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    //get Theme_name
    hm = db.getBookTheme();
    if(hm.isEmpty() == true){
        System.out.println("not have data");
    }else{
        //prepare theme, title, book_id 
        list_theme = hm.get("theme");
        list_title = hm.get("title");
        list_bokID = hm.get("bokID");
    }

    LinearLayout gallery = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.images_gallery);
    //image fullsize 
    final ImageView imgFullSize = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.full_size_image);

    for (String themeName : list_theme) {
        //prepare image in layout gallery 
        ImageView img_shelf = new ImageView(this);
        img_shelf.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        img_shelf.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        img_shelf.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        //set image resource
        resID = getResources().getIdentifier(themeName, "drawable", getPackageName());
        img_shelf.setImageResource(resID);


    }

    // img_shelf set it in on click
                img_shelf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        ImageView selectedImage = (ImageView) v;
                        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) selectedImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                        if(imgOldSelected != null){
                            imgOldSelected.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        }
                        selectedImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

                    }
                });

                gallery.addView(img_shelf);
}
```

}

this is my logcat error

```
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.splash.bookguk_project/category_viewbook_sub2_1.MybookActivity_Gallery}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at category_viewbook_sub2_1.MybookActivity_Gallery.onCreate(MybookActivity_Gallery.java:73)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
 02-21 16:12:02.421: E/AndroidRuntime(29116):   ... 11 more
```

thank you

Comment: Which line is number 73 in your onCreate?

Comment: MybookActivity_Gallery.java:73 line..

Comment: `img_shelf` is null probably.

Comment: why null pointer in line 73 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `img_shelf` variable on the class and then you redefine it again in the loop (so it's instantiated only within the scope of the loop):

```
for (String themeName : list_theme) {
    //prepare image in layout gallery 
    ImageView img_shelf = new ImageView(this);
    ...
}
```

This won't work as intended.

I'm not sure how you wanted to use it though as it seems that you create multiple `ImageView`'s but then attach `OnClickListener` to only one of them. You will need to either move the code for `OnClickListener` into the loop or create a variable - list of `ImageView` on the class.

Answer (score 2):

You have this ImageView delcared an initialized inside for loop

```
   for (String themeName : list_theme) {
    //prepare image in layout gallery 
    ImageView img_shelf = new ImageView(this);
    //this iamgeview is not added to gridview or to the layout
   }
```

So you have a `NullPointerException` @

```
   img_shelf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // outside for loop
```

coz

```
   private ImageView img_shelf;  // is declared not initialized
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Also the `ImageView` declared and initialized in for loop is not added to gridview or activity.